# Reporting services 2008 on Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Can I use Reporting Services 2008 with SQL Server 2005 database? 
Do I need both licenses (for SQL server 2008 and SQL server 2005)
Do I need two instances (SQL Server 2008 and Sql server 2005) or can Reporting Services 2008 be "installed" as add on to Sql server 2005?

Thanks for answers,
  Matra

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can install the database on a SQL Server 2005 instance. However, you very much need another license for SSRS 2008. It's an entirely different product. It is, by far, not just a SQL Server 2005 "add-on."

Comment: As Eric said, you will need a license for both products unless you have software assurance.  But why not upgrade?  You can run the database in SQL Server 2005 compatibility mode so that nothing on it should have to change.

Comment: Aye, Jeff has a point. Also, databases migrate *very* easily. Just detach and attach. No conversions or anything. Pretty nifty.

Comment: Thank guys. The reason why I need 2005 is that there is some other product that is not officialy certified on 2008 (even for compatiblity mode). It looks like we will have to use 2 licenses... Matra