# SSRS 2008 Reporting Services on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I know that the only stupid question is the one that you don't ask ... but even so this could be borderline :)

Is it possible to install SSRS 2008 [stand alone] on a site that has SQL server 2005 installed.

I know that you can store the SSRS 2008 Report and Temp databases on SQL Server 2005 [With some restrictions based on the SSRS edition and the SQL server edition].

If SSRS 2008 is an integral part of SQL Server 2008 and can't be separated then our SQL Server 2005 customers will have to upgrade to SQL Server 2008.

Its closely related to here 
[Reporting services 2008 on Sql Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287761/reporting-services-2008-on-sql-server-2005)
but I would like some further clarification.

Thanks in advance,

Liam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to install SSRS 2008 [stand alone] on a site that has SQL server 2005 installed.

No. There is no SSRS-only installation.