# SSRS 2005 and SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

Is is possible to use SSRS 2005 with SQL Server 2008? I've got it almost hooked up, but keep getting this error: "The report server installation is not initialized. (rsReportServerNotActivated) (rsRPCError)". In SSRS Config Manager, the initialization button is greyed out, although on the Server Status pane it shows "Initialized: Yes".

This question is the reverse of this one: [Reporting services 2008 on Sql Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287761/reporting-services-2008-on-sql-server-2005).

Comment: Not sure I understand your configuration. Is it SSRS 2005 which uses SQL 2008 as catalog server?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about why you are trying to configure SSRS 2005 with a SQL Server 2008 database? Are they instances on different servers?

Comment: @user1578107: yes, I am trying to connect SSRS 2005 to SQL Server 2008;

Comment: @Nathan: yes, they are instances on different servers; the reason we're trying this is to accomodate a third-party app, long story, point is, we have to try this.

Comment: Are the report catalog and temp databases you created set to compatibility level 90? rsReportServerNotActivated indicates something went wrong when generating the encryption keys needed for the web service to connect with the database. If you check this article about moving report server 2005 databases to another computer, it explicitly states the new server must be the same version of SQL Server so unfortunately I think it's unlikely that you will get this to work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156421(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: However, as you have a SQL 2005 instance on a separate server can you install the SQL 2005 database engine on the report server itself and create the report server databases there?

Comment: from error code, it seems that you're trying to connect SSRS2005 to the catalog database created by SSRS2008, that just wont work.